# Azure DevOps Delivery Plan (Preview) - Not all features are showing

Tags: azure-devops, devops, agile, azure-boards

I am discovering the Azure Delivery Plan but I don't understand why I don't see all my Features in there.
This is what I am talking about:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=plans-preview

I have looked at the Tags, owners, start/end dates, and so on but can not find any criteria which indicate why I see certain Features and not others.
I am also a member of the projects that I do not see.

Can anyone shed some light for me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is actually on me and was kind of logical.
The features were on the backlog and didn't have any iteration assigned, hence, there were not showing below any iteration.

Thank you for the suggestions and feedback! Case closed!

Answer (score 2):

In my test, if the dates of two iterations overlap, the features under the iteration will not be displayed.

For example:

[image]

If the date does not overlap, the features under the iteration will be displayed normally.

[image]

You can check if this is your case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Hugh Lin - MSFT ! Unfortunately, ours are not overlapping (see image) each other ... Any other suggestions/directions to look at? https://ibb.co/RjR7Ztr

Comment: Check your plan to see if the teams where all features are added. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axZ7n.png)